# gradle issue in android

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

```
PS C:\Users\gulsh\StudioProjects\crudfirebase\android> cd android
cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\gulsh\StudioProjects\crudfirebase\android\android' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd android
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\gulsh\...android\android:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
 
PS C:\Users\gulsh\StudioProjects\crudfirebase\android> cd android
cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\gulsh\StudioProjects\crudfirebase\android\android' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd android
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\gulsh\...android\android:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
 
PS C:\Users\gulsh\StudioProjects\crudfirebase\android> --stacktrace
At line:1 char:3
+ --stacktrace
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:1 char:3
+ --stacktrace
+   ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'stacktrace' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
 
PS C:\Users\gulsh\StudioProjects\crudfirebase\android> --info
At line:1 char:3
+ --info
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:1 char:3
+ --info
+   ~~~~
Unexpected token 'info' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

I want `sha-1` key. I have set path of JDK and also `flutter doctor` does not report any issue, it's all set.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.